# Can't connect to external SQL Server using eclipse on my phone

Tags: android, sql, eclipse

I have a button on my Android app screen and when clicked it calls

```
AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
runner.execute();
```

My doInBackground does the following

```
try {

  Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

  String serverAddress;
  String dbpassword;
  String dbusername;
  String dbName;    

  serverAddress="external_ip:port";
  dbpassword="password";
  dbusername="sa";
  dbName= "dbname";

  resp="HERE Start" ;

  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + serverAddress + "/" + dbName, dbusername, dbpassword);

   resp="HERE End" ;


} catch (SQLException e)
{
   resp="HERE error"+ e.getMessage() ;
}
```

When I run this on an emulator it works fine and can add and read data from the table (I have removed that code for now)

I connected my mobile to the PC and used my phone to connect and when I press the button I get the following message.

Unfortunately, appName has stopped.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: if I include my instance name in the connection string I get the same error

Comment: Can someone tell me why I have been down voted! Surely I'm not alone with this problem

Comment: Cannot connect to sqlserver when my android phone is connected to pc thorugh usb. had the same problem a year ago, questioned not marked as answered!

Answer (score 0):

Just as a guess, this might not be doing what you think it is. Since you're identifying the db server by an IP Address, it should be trying to use TCP to connect, which means it's probably using whatever WiFi it's connected to rather than e.g. a USB connection. This may give you security problems as a connection from a random device (your phone) may well be rejected by the db server - as it should be. It may also refuse the connection due to it not being able to authenticate the caller as being from an allowed domain or work group (not sure how to get around that for a phone).

You could use [TCPView from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) running on the server to see whether any requests are incoming.

Not an answer to your problem, I know, but it may clarify it.